# Python monitor process by pid

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I'm looking for better idea than my or may be you can show me where I made a mistake. What I'm trying to do.

1. I try to run process with subprocess and thread it is run good and no mistakes here found, one thing that's command in Linux has timeout.
2. I got pid
   3.Than I would like monitor proc by pid, and when it finished do some stuff

```
def monitor_func(my_obj):
               print(my_obj.process_pid)
               sleep(20)
               while os.kill(my_obj.process_pid, 0) is None:
                     print("proc is running")
                     try:
                         os.kill(my_obj.process_pid, 0)
                     except OSError:
                         continue
               else:
                      print("proc is stopped")
```

What is the problem? While loop works in infinite. os.kill(my_obj.process_pid, 0) always returns NONE
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I got you right, but I am assuming you are trying to figure out if some process is still running by PID.

The main issue with your code is the fact [`os.kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) doesn't retrun any value, so you will always get `None`. So the loop will never cease.

---

Consider the following:

```py
def monitor_func(pid): # no need to pass the object as we aren't using it
    print(pid)
    while True:
      try:
        os.kill(pid, 0) # 0 doesn't send any signal, but does error checks
      except OSError:
        print("Proc exited")
      else:
        print("Proc is still running")
        sleep(20)
```

This will mostly work assuming you are using the correct PID, and have aproporaite permissions.

Comment: thanks a lot, issue resolved, I run external processes without threads `code`subprocess.Popen`code`. thank you!